# How to set the time in MS since 1970 to a Datetime(6) field in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, datetime-format, date-manipulation

I have a Java application where I get a timestamp with the call System.currentTimeInMills();

This returns values like 1331255526000.

Now I want to store these values in a MySQL database in a Datetime(6) field and I've written the following query:

> $sql = 'INSERT INTO attention '.
>          '(ParticipantID,SessionId, Timestamp, Attention) '.
>          'VALUES (' .$participant. ',' .$session. ',FROM_UNIXTIME(' .$timestamp. '),' .$attention. ')';

Where the variable $timestamp is the value I retrieve in Java.

However, this query is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the use of java tag here

Comment: What error do you have ?

Comment: @JqueryLearner Because the time in milliseconds value is from java

Comment: @FischerLudrian no need to include java tag because you clearly mentioned you get 1331255526000 but you have problem in php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in mysql: `from_unixtime($yourvariable / 1000)`

Mysql timestamps are not in ms , but in seconds.

Comment: Yes, but I want milliseconds precision.

Comment: Have you tried it? It should give you the fractions. Only when working with temp values, before MySQL version 5.6.4, the fractions would go lost. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html